# How to count lines with word after line where is word2 -bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a big text file where some lines contain the word `"DataMeetingIs11"` where the following line contains the word `"done"`. My task is to count all such lines. For example I want to count the following:

```
......DataMeetingIs11.....
....done..................
```

but not the following:

```
 ......DataMeetingIs11.....
 ..........................
```

I tried using the next command:

```
grep -A 1 DataMeetingIs11 file| grep -c done
```

but it didn't work. Can you please help me?

Edit

How can i count lines without "done" words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk instead:

```
awk '/DataMeetingIs11/ {a++; p=NR} /done/ && NR==(p+1) {c++} 
     END{print "Without done:", (a-c) ", With done:", c}' file
Without done: 1, With done: 2
```

**Explanation:**

```
/DataMeetingIs11/    # when input line matches literal "DataMeetingIs11"
{a++; p=NR}          # store current line # NR into variable p and increment a
/done/ && NR==(p+1)  # when line matches "done" and when 
                     # current line # is p+1 (next line)
{c++}                # increment a counter c
END{print (a-c), c}  # print counts the end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have another question how to count lines without "done" word , like grep -v  in bash ?

Comment: ok check my updated answer for getting both counts from same command. Also may I know why you removed accepted mark?

Answer (score 1):

In case you know (from the structure of your data), that the word 'done' will NOT occur on the same line as DataMeetingIs11, this should work too (provided you have Gnu grep, so that the -A flag is recognized):

```
fgrep -A 1 DataMeetingIs11 your_file|fgrep -c done
```

Comment: Thank you, can you help me with no "done" lines after DataMeetingIs11
> fgrep -A 1 DataMeetingIs11 your_file|fgrep -v -c done , didn't work

Comment: May I suggest starting a new thread for this? Things are easier to discuss, if different questions are handled in different threads.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with the 'not done' lines is to count the total number of data meeting lines too, and the number of 'not done' lines is the total minus the number of 'done' lines.  Or use `awk` or Perl or Python, …

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, which assumes that the file will fit as a whole into memory, would be Perl:

```
perl -n -l -w -0777 -e 'print scalar(()=/DataMeetingIs11.*\n.*done/g)' your_file
```

-0777 is "Perl Magic" to deliver the whole file as a single string, instead of processing it line-by-line.

-n takes care that the file content is stored in Perl's "magic variable" $_

The Regexp matches what you are looking for, and the modifier 'g' tells Perl to match it as often as possible.

'()=' puts the regexp into so-called "list mode". A regexp in list mode returns the list of matches.

The 'scalar(...)' operator turns a list in the number of elements in the list, which is then printed to stdout.

-l ensures that a newline is printed afterwards.