# How to count lines without word after line where is word2 -bash

Tags: linux, bash

Hello i have question related to 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193008/how-to-count-lines-with-word-after-line-where-is-word2-bash/29193347?noredirect=1#comment46601248_29193347)

I have a big text file where some lines contain the word `"DataMeetingIs11"` where the following line contains the word `"done"` or note . My task is to count all such lines. For example I want to count this lines without "done " word

```
grep -A 1 DataMeetingIs11 your_file|fgrep -v -c
```

didn't work

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show us a small example with the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-P` Perl-regexp parameter to achieve the above.

```
grep -oPz '.*DataMeetingIs11.*(?=\n.*done)' file | wc -l
```

Add word boundaries if necessary.

```
grep -oPz '.*\bDataMeetingIs11\b.*(?=\n.*\bdone\b)' file | wc -l
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat fa
 DataMeetingIs11
done
foo
bar
 DataMeetingIs11
not 
 DataMeetingIs11
fio done
$ grep -oPz '.*DataMeetingIs11.*(?=\n.*done)' fa | wc -l
2
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a awk script you can also do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$0 ~ /DataMeetingIs11/ {
    line=$0
    next
}
$0 ~ /done/ && line != "" {
    count++
}
{
    line = ""
}
END {
    print count
}
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
blabla
 DataMeetingIs11
done
something
 DataMeetingIs11
alt
 DataMeetingIs11
it's done
```

**Execution result on this file:**

```
$ ./DataMeetingIs11.awk file
2
```